# Sorting big array

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

i have an array with ~500k objects, and when begin sorting, my app is crashes.
_objects is NSMutableArray. Advice me some methods how to make fast sorting of big array.

```
  - (void)sort1 {
        [_objects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            NSNumber *first = [(Obj *)a name];
            NSNumber *second = [(Obj *)b name];
            return [second compare:first];
        }];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: Do you know *why* the app crashed?  For example, was it due to running out of memory, or something else?  Does it work with smaller arrays?

Comment: 500k objects? Are you serious? you must plan fetching data using indexing...

Comment: If you're going to have 500k objects with NSNumbers you might as well just use pure C so that it's faster.

Comment: falls because of running out of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Sort smaller portions of the array in sequence, and then merge them together (which could be done in multiple stages).
- Taking that idea further, you could use one or more files to store intermediate arrays, and thus reduce the amount of memory needed (though that would most likely slow things down, its better than crashing)

Comment: Basically what is being described is a "merge sort".

Answer (score 2):

With that much data, you might consider using a different approach. After all, no one is likely to scroll through a tableview containing ~500k items. It might make more sense to store the data in an SQLITE database, and then query the DB for the items of interest and sort only those items.